# Cómo actualizar las Celdas de una Collection View en Swift 4 - tanto el contenido como el backgroundColor -

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Estoy desarrollando un juego donde utilizo una Collection View cuyas Celdas contienen una Label y utilizo el valor de esa etiqueta y el color de fondo de la Celda.

En Swift 4 y Xcode.

Una vez que el jugador hace un grupo de jugadas, que las guardo, quiero repetir sus jugadas cambiando el color de las celdas que estoy tratando y después el valor de la etiqueta.

Para cargar las Celdas utilizo un Array con los valores de cada una y además tengo otro Array con los colores de cada Celda.

Durante el juego, mientras el jugador pulsa las Celdas, no tengo ningún problema y tanto los valores como los colores de las Celdas se mantienen y cambian perfectamente. Me funcionan los reloadData.

Pero cuando intento repetir las jugadas no me hace caso para nada. Os pongo el código donde me ocurre y también algún otro que creo que puede ayudar.

Aquí está el problema (o eso creo):

```
func avanzar(camino: [[[Int]]], velocidad: Int) {
    for grupos in camino {
        for parejas in grupos {         // Pulsamos de una en una las celdas de las parejas, cambiando color
            // Guardo el VALOR de la Celda primera del grupo
            // Elegimos el color de las celdas marcadas según el valor                
            // Al ser la primera la ponemos en color pendiente
            let celdaVersion_1 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[0]]
            let celdaVersion_2 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[1]]
            indexCelda1 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_1, section: 0)
            indexCelda2 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_2, section: 0)
            let celda1 = celdaCollectionView2.cellForItem(at: indexCelda1)
            let celda2 = celdaCollectionView2.cellForItem(at: indexCelda2)
            celda1?.backgroundColor = color6
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = color6
            // Lo intento de dos maneras, también lo he hecho con deleteIteme e insertItems y nada
            self.celdaCollectionView2.reloadItems(at: [indexCelda1])
            self.celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()

            ....
            celda1?.backgroundColor = colorElegido
            celda2?.backgroundColor = colorElegido
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = colorElegido
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_2)] = colorElegido
            self.celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()
            .....

        }
        anotarJugada(grupo: grupos)
    }
}
```

Las funciones y la Collection View:

```
@IBOutlet weak var celdaCollectionView2: UICollectionView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return matrix.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let celda = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! celdaCollectionViewCell
    celda.etiqueta2.text = imageData[matrix [indexPath.row]]
    celda.backgroundColor = matrixColor[indexPath.row]
    celda.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    return celda
}
```

También:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    celdaCollectionView2.delegate = self
    celdaCollectionView2.dataSource = self
    .....
}
```

Y la Celda:

```
//  celdaCollectionViewCell.swift
import UIKit
class celdaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {    
    @IBOutlet weak var etiqueta2: UILabel!
}
```

Si necesitáis más información...

Gracias.

Hola de nuevo, he hecho avances en el problema:

Lo primero que hice fue modificar la forma de actualizar las Celdas, haciendo **deleteItems / insertItems**. Además lo hago con **performBatchUpdates** y funciona igual.

Pero he observado lo siguiente:

La repetición de las Jugadas se ejecuta al pulsar un botón de la pantalla, mediante la función: **func avanzar(camino: [[[Int]]], ...)**

Dicha función repite todos los movimientos del jugador, uno tras otro, pero permaneciendo la pantalla impasible y después de rehacer todas las jugadas presenta en la pantalla el final de la partida, es decir **había realizado los movimientos y actualizaciones de los datos pero no refresca la collectionView en la pantalla**.

Nota: entre cada movimiento tengo puesto un temporizador para poder ver la jugada.

He modificado la función de avanzar y ahora lo hace de jugada en jugada, es decir cada pulsación del botón avanza una jugada y funciona pero no es cuestión de que el jugador esté pulsando un montón de veces.

**Deduzco que "dentro" de la función no actualiza la collectionView a pesar de actualizar los datos y atributos y cuando la función finaliza y devuelve el control es cuando se actualiza.**

Os pongo el nuevo código:

```
@IBAction func avanceJugador(_ sender: Any) {
    if paso < caminosJugador.count - 1 {
        avanzarPaso(camino: caminosJugador, paso: paso, velocidad: velocidadSeleccionada)
        paso = paso + 1
        filasEnBlanco2 = Int(buscarFilasBlanco(matrizFilasBlanco: matrixPartida))
        matrixVersion = crearMatrixVersion(matrizAVersionar: matrixPartida)
        crearMatrixVersionRevuelta()
        // Ahora puedo generar matrix
        pintarMatrixPartida()
        celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()
    }
}
func avanzarPaso(camino: [[[Int]]], paso: Int, velocidad: Int32) {
    if paso > camino.count - 1 {
        // Fin del camino
    } else {
        for parejas in camino[paso] {
            let valorPrimera = matrix [matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[0]]]      // Guardo el VALOR de la Celda primera del grupo
            // Ojo, quizá hay que tener cuidado con los índices relativos
            // Elegimos el color de las celdas marcadas según el valor
            switch valorPrimera {
            ...
            default: colorElegido = UIColor.white
            }
            // Al ser la primera la ponemos en color pendiente
            let celdaVersion_1 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[0]]
            let celdaVersion_2 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[1]]
            indexCelda1 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_1, section: 0)
            indexCelda2 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_2, section: 0)
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = UIColor.white
            celdaCollectionView2.scrollToItem(at: indexCelda1, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
            // collectionView.scrollToItem(at: ip, at: .centerHorizontally, animated: true)
            updateItems(accion: "delete", indice: indexCelda1)
            updateItems(accion: "insert", indice: indexCelda1)
            celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()

            usleep(useconds_t(velocidad))

            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = colorElegido
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_2)] = colorElegido
            updateItems(accion: "delete", indice: indexCelda1)
            updateItems(accion: "insert", indice: indexCelda1)
            updateItems(accion: "delete", indice: indexCelda2)
            updateItems(accion: "insert", indice: indexCelda2)
            celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()

            usleep(useconds_t(velocidad))
        }
        anotarJugada(grupo: camino[paso])
    }
}
func anotarJugada(grupo: [[Int]]) {
    // A la vez vamos poniendo a 0 las Celdas de matrixPartida
    // Hay que tener en cuenta que el índice a 0 de matrixPartida
    // es el contenido de la Celda de matrixVersion con índice igual que matrix
    filasEnBlanco1 = Int(buscarFilasBlanco(matrizFilasBlanco: matrixPartida))
    for i in 0 ... grupo.count - 1 {
        let celdaVersion_1 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[grupo[i][0]]
        let celdaVersion_2 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[grupo[i][1]]
        indexCelda1 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_1, section: 0)
        indexCelda2 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_2, section: 0)
        matrixPartida[matrixVersion[celdaVersion_1]] = 0
        matrixPartida[matrixVersion[celdaVersion_2]] = 0
        matrix[celdaVersion_1] = 0
        matrix[celdaVersion_2] = 0
        matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = colorElegido
        matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_2)] = colorElegido
        // Esto es de prueba
        updateItems(accion: "delete", indice: indexCelda1)
        updateItems(accion: "insert", indice: indexCelda1)
        updateItems(accion: "delete", indice: indexCelda2)
        updateItems(accion: "insert", indice: indexCelda2)
        celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()

        usleep(useconds_t(velocidadSeleccionada))
    }
    limpiarColores()
    ....
    matrixVersion = crearMatrixVersion(matrizAVersionar: matrixPartida)
    crearMatrixVersionRevuelta()
    // Ahora puedo generar matrix
    pintarMatrixPartida()
    celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()
}
func updateItems(accion: String, indice: IndexPath) {
        celdaCollectionView2.performBatchUpdates({
            if accion == "insert" {
                celdaCollectionView2.insertItems(at: [indice])
                itemsContador += 1
            } else {
                if accion == "delete" {
                    celdaCollectionView2.deleteItems(at: [indice])
                    itemsContador -= 1
                }
            }
        }, completion: nil)
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsContador
    }
```

Espero que me podáis ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: Que lenguaje seria este? es mas importante eso como etiqueta que la que pusiste, que realmetne no dice nada

Comment: Puedes probar con
`celdaCollectionView2.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, ya he entendido lo que me decía Spidvmp y he solucionado el problema utilizando Timer.scheduledTimer de forma correcta, este es el código:

```
var timerTemp : Timer?    
@IBAction func avanceJugador(_ sender: Any) {
            if(timerTemp == nil){
                timerTemp = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(avanceTemp), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            }
    }
    @objc func avanceTemp(){
        if paso < caminosJugador.count {
            ejecutarAvance(camino: caminosJugador)
            paso = paso + 1
        }else{
            timerTemp?.invalidate()
        }
    }

    func ejecutarAvance(camino: [[[Int]]]) {

            avanzarJugada(camino: caminosJugador, paso: paso, velocidad: velocidadSeleccionada)
    }
```

Muchas gracias **Spidvmp**

Answer (score 0):

Según parece tu problema no esta en recoger, guardar y poder acceder a la información para reproducirla, el problema esta en el momento de mostrarla. Me voy a centrar en eso. Yo cambiaría 2 cosas. Para actualizar la collectionView, no es necesario quitar la celda y volver ponerla, puedes utilizar el método para recargar solo unos indices

```
collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(myArrayOfIndexPaths)
```

y en myArrayOfIndexPaths tendras un array de todos los indices que hay que recargar. Imagino que sera un array de solo 1 elemento.

Tu segundo problema es que solo se ve el resultado final. Por un lado es lógico, estas poniendo todas las actualizaciones de la collectionView en un método y que lo pinte en un bucle, pues lo hace y cuando sale del método lo renderiza. La solución que has puesto de un sleep en mitad del bucle, no es buena opción, te va a bloquear la app, no va a salir de ahi hasta que termine la reproducción. Deberías hacer una reproducción por cada llamada a un método para que lo renderice. He hecho una pequeña prueba. He creado un proyecto con una collectionView y una celda. He creado un modelo de 50 elementos random y que se pinta la collectionView. Luego llamo un método para y cambiando el modelo. Tu esa parte ya la tienes hecha y te funciona, pero no se pinta bien. Mira mi código

```
var modelo: [Bool] = []



@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for _ in 0...50 {
        modelo.append(randomBool())
    }
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.aleatorio()
}

@objc func aleatorio() {
```

//aqui sacarias un valor y se muestra en la collectionView
        let i = randomIndex()
        self.modelo[i] = randomBool()
        let ip = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [ip])
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(aleatorio), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

```
func randomBool() -> Bool {
    return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
}

func randomIndex() -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(50))
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "celda", for: indexPath)
    if modelo[indexPath.row] == true {
        c.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        c.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    return c
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.modelo.count
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

Muchas gracias, he seguido tus consejos y he cambiado los insert y delete por reload y eliminar los sleep.
También he creado

```
@objc func refrescarCelda() {
        celdaCollectionView2.scrollToItem(at: indiceCelda, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
        self.celdaCollectionView2.reloadItems(at: [indiceCelda])
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(refrescarCelda), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
```

A la que llamo cada vez que tengo preparados el valor y color en el modelo, pero me sigue esperando a actualizar o renderizar hasta el final de mi bucle de preparar los datos y actualizarlos, ya qye tengo que hacer un bucle para que se ejecuten los movimientos automáticamente.

Debo de tener un error de concepto. He probado a poner el bucle en la misma llamada del IBAction, en una función aparte,... pero nada.
Este es el código nuevo:

```
@IBAction func avanceJugador(_ sender: Any) {
        ejecutarAvance(camino: caminosJugador)
    }
    func ejecutarAvance(camino: [[[Int]]]) {
        for paso in 0...camino.count - 1 {
            avanzarJugada(camino: camino, paso: paso, velocidad: velocidadSeleccionada)
        }
    }
func avanzarJugada(camino: [[[Int]]], paso: Int, velocidad: Int32) {
        arrayCeldas.removeAll()
        let grupo = camino[paso]
        for parejas in grupo {
            let valorPrimera = matrix [matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[0]]]      // Guardo el VALOR de la Celda primera del grupo
            // Ojo, quizá hay que tener cuidado con los índices relativos
            // Elegimos el color de las celdas marcadas según el valor
            switch valorPrimera {
            case 1: colorElegido = color1
            case 2: colorElegido = color2
            case 3: colorElegido = color3
            case 4: colorElegido = color4
            case 5: colorElegido = color5
            case 6: colorElegido = color4
            case 7: colorElegido = color3
            case 8: colorElegido = color2
            case 9: colorElegido = color1
            //            default: colorElegido = color6
            default: colorElegido = UIColor.white
            }
            // Al ser la primera la ponemos en color pendiente
            let celdaVersion_1 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[0]]
            let celdaVersion_2 = matrixPartidaRevuelta[parejas[1]]
            indexCelda1 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_1, section: 0)
            indexCelda2 = IndexPath(row: celdaVersion_2, section: 0)
            arrayCeldas.append(indexCelda1)
            arrayCeldas.append(indexCelda2)
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = color6
            indiceCelda = indexCelda1
            refrescarCelda()

            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_1)] = colorElegido
            matrixColor[Int(celdaVersion_2)] = colorElegido

            indiceCelda = indexCelda1
            refrescarCelda()
            indiceCelda = indexCelda2
            refrescarCelda()
        }

        for celdaI in arrayCeldas {
            matrixPartida[matrixVersion[celdaI.row]] = 0
            matrix[celdaI.row] = 0
            matrixColor[celdaI.row] = UIColor.white
            indiceCelda = celdaI
            refrescarCelda()
        }
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let celda = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! celdaCollectionViewCell
        celda.etiqueta2.text = imageData[matrix [indexPath.row]]
        celda.backgroundColor = matrixColor[indexPath.row]
        celda.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        return celda
    }
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he seguido todos tus consejos, sustituir los insert y delete por reload y eliminar los sleep. También he creado una func con Timer A la que llamo cada vez que tengo preparados lel valor y color en el modelo, pero me sigue esperando a actualizar o renderizar hasta e final de mi bucle de preparar los datos y actualizarlos.
Debo de tener un error de concepto. He probado a poner el bucle en la misma llamada del IBAction, en una función aparte,... Pongo el código en la pregunta por espacio. repioto muchas gracias.